# keyupand setinterval not functioning properly

Tags: jquery

Am trying to run a page when a key is pressed in a textarea but and it will be refreshing until they is nothing in the textarea but when i run the script, it will run when the key is pressed but wont stop even when the textarea is empty, here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("textarea").keyup(function(){     

            var comment = $('.the-new-com');
            if( comment.val() !== '')
            { 
                $("#is_typing").show();
                setInterval(function(){
                    $('#is_typing').load('everything/processing/is_typing.php?chat_id='+<?php echo $id; ?>);
                }, 1000); 
            }
            else{
                $("#is_typing").hide();
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking but I suspect you need [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").keyup(function(){     
        var comment = $('.the-new-com'), interval;
        if( comment.val() !== '')
        { 
            $("#is_typing").show();
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                $('#is_typing').load('abc.com');
            }, 1000); 
        } else {
            $("#is_typing").hide();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }); 
});
```